# Why I'm getting Identifier 'X' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a memberAngular in typscript 3.4.3?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following deceleration in my component:

```
public trips: TripObj[] = [];
```

After the initialisation, I'm trying to display the array in template which is
working fine, but there is annoying error, look like typescript error.

Here is the template:

```
<li *ngFor="let data of trips  | slice:start:end" [ngClass]="data.visibility_css_class">
```

Here is the trip object:

```
import { Trip } from '../_models';

export class TripObj {
  public trip?: Trip;  
  public visibility_css_class?: string;

  constructor(trip: Trip) {
    this.trip = trip;
  }

}
```

The error I got is from the field data.visibility_css_class in the template.
The complete error is:

```
Identifier 'visibility_css_class' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a memberAngular
```

If I remove the pipe  "| slice:start:end" from the loop, all the error disappear but I need this pipe to limit the number results in the page.

Comment: try to print one of the data on the console after initialization if you may not get it !?

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message? Why do you have a `|` after trips in your ngFor. That doen't look like valid code to me.

Comment: I'll updated the question as I found the issue that causing it, but not sure what to do.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxxhnw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), but I don't get any error.

Comment: interesting. I'm using typescript 3.4.3 maybe it was fixed in your version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the slice from the template and done in the component:

```
this.trips = this.trips.slice(this.start,this.end);
```

It looks like from typescript 3, it's not allowed to do this logic in the template.
Hope it help someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always wanted to do the slicing in the component. Is there another solution where we can keep doning this in